# hi how can help me and resolve "Cordova.exec() is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/plugin.js" error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i was trying to implement a simple push notification application using some plugins. a this moment i have an problem with a javaScript file when i click on a bouton how call a javaScript function called `register` , that show me an error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cordova is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/GCMPlugin.js
```

this is my GCMPlugin.js

```
        (function () {

    var GCM = function() {};

    GCM.prototype.register = function(senderID, eventCallback, successCallback, failureCallback) {

      if ( typeof eventCallback != "string") {   // The eventCallback has to be a STRING name not the actual routine like success/fail routines
        var e = new Array();
        e.msg = 'eventCallback must be a STRING name of the routine';
        e.rc = -1;
        failureCallback( e );
        return;
      }

      return Cordova.exec(successCallback,      
                  failureCallback,      
                  'GCMPlugin',        
                  'register',             
                  [{ senderID: senderID, ecb : eventCallback }]);   
                                };

    if (cordova.addPlugin) {
      cordova.addConstructor(function() {
        //Register the javascript plugin with Cordova
        cordova.addPlugin('GCM', new GCM());
      });
    } else {
        if (!window.plugins) {
            window.plugins = {};
        }
      window.plugins.GCM = new GCM();
    }
})();
```

the function register in index.js :

```
function register()
{ window.plugins.GCM.register("1193127317675", "GCM_Event", GCM_Success, GCM_Fail ); }
```

this is my index.html  :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>M W A</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="GCMPlugin.js"></script> <!-- GCM Cordova plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery_1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<!-- Include my Javascript routines -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="CORDOVA_GCM_script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>

        <input type="button" value="Register" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;" onclick="register();" >
        <input type="button" value="Unregister" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;" onclick="unregister();" >
</body>
</html>
```

note : that i use `cordova-2.1.0.js` ! and when i use `cordova.js` (3.0.0) i get that `exec() call to unknown plugin: GCMPlugin` 
can u help me to resolve this problem .. i spend more than 3 days to resolve it but i still have this problem

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cordova is not defined at file:

Seems you forgot to add cordova js script to your assets folder.

If you want to use GCM, you should do the following:
At first, you should have installed GCM plugin (https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova).

For cordova 3.0 you just have to add this lines to your res/xml/config.xml file.

```
<feature name="GCMPlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.plugin.GCM.GCMPlugin" /> 
</feature>
```

Instead of `<plugin name="GCMPlugin" value="com.plugin.GCM.GCMPlugin" />`

That's because of `<plugin>` deprecated in cordova 3.*